# How to monitor a file descriptor for new data availability?

Tags: linux, polling, file-descriptor

Consider the following code snippet.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/poll.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int fd;
    char buf[1024];
    int i;
    struct pollfd pfds;
    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);

    while (1) {
        pfds.fd = fd;
        pfds.events = POLLIN;

        poll(&pfds, 1, -1);

        if (pfds.revents & POLLIN) {
            i = read(fd, buf, 1024);

            write(1, buf, i);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This program receives a file name, opens the corresponding file, and "poll"s its file descriptor in order to monitor data in availability. Whenever `poll` detects data in availability, those new data are printed.

However, what happens with this program? If the file I want to monitor already contained data when the program is launched, its contents are printed. That's ok. But, later, when I edit the file with a text editor and save it, my program doesn't print the new data.

So, how to monitor a regular file descriptor (not a file using its path) for new data availability? Do I have to use another function other than `poll`? Or am I missing any `pollfd` flag?

Comment: Maybe you should call [fstat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat) and check for `EBADF`, but it would help to actually look at the return value of the `poll` system call first!

Comment: `poll` doesn't work for regular disk files.

Answer (score 6):

You can't use `poll` on regular files to watch for changes. However, there are several other ways. The classic approach is to call `fstat` at regular intervals with the open file descriptor, and compare the returned fields with the previous fields (in particular `st_size`). A modern approach is to use `inotify(7)` for monitoring files. For example recent versions of GNU tail use this approach:

```
$ strace tail -f /tmp/foobar
...
open("/tmp/foobar", O_RDONLY) ) = 3
...
inotify_init() = 4
inotify_add_watch(4, "/tmp/foobar", IN_MODIFY|IN_ATTRIB|IN_DELETE_SELF|IN_MOVE_SELF) = 1
...
read(4, ...
```

See the manual page [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) for more information on how that works.